# How to make Content Tree visible with the newly created role?

Tags: sitecore-client

I created a new user role, and made this role member of Author. Then added access rights on several items. When I logged in using the newly created user and access content editor, I found out that the content tree is hidden. I want the Content Tree, Tempalte, Layout, and Media Library to be visible. I already added a permission to use them. But still it is hidden. Any advise on how to fix this?

Comment: Does it help if you use choose `VIEW` ribbon and select `Entire tree` option?

Comment: Yes, selecting the Entire Tree and Hidden Items solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are special items because they are marked as hidden.

You can either go to view in the content editor and check "hidden items". That is on a user base.
[image]

Second option is to unhide these folders, by going to the configure tab. Unprotect item, make item visible and protect item again.

[image]

Comment: Yes, selecting the Entire Tree and Hidden Items solved the issue. Thanks!